# How to handle differently sized type in C library from C++

Tags: c++, c

I have an external C library that I link to from C++.
The library defines a struct that uses *bool* and includes a typedef for it for C.
The problem is that this typedef uses an **int**, so (on my platform) instead of this *bool* having a size of 1 byte, it is 4 bytes big.

When I then #include the header and create the struct in C++, *bool* (being the C++ standard type) has a size of 1 byte and thus the struct has a completely different memory layout, which causes all kinds of stack corruptions when I pass it to the C library in order to modify it there.

Is there a way to fix this situation without modifying the external library? I guess compiling the external library with a C++ compiler instead of a C compiler would work, correct? Is this my only chance of fixing this?

lib.h:

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
typedef int bool;
#endif

typedef struct {
  int numValues;
  bool values[20];
} bArray;

int arraySize();
```

lib.c:

```
#include "lib.h"

int arraySize() {
    return sizeof(bArray);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
#include "lib.h"
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "size in c++: " << sizeof(bArray) << std::endl
              << "size in c  : " << arraySize() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
size in c++: 24
size in c  : 84
```

Comment: Most compilers have a `push()` /  `pop()` `#pragma ` directive how exactly alignment should be handled for a structure declaration.

Comment: Lose the `bool` typedef in your C code.  It's a C++ keyword, so it's a bad idea to even try.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I do not think this question has anything to do with alignment.

Comment: One option would be to just give up and use the C type in your C++ program. Then they would agree. Not great, but it *is* an option.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Could well be, yes. Anyways, if you want to ensure the `#pragma` may help.

Comment: when I see something like this I don't trust library, but I'm starting search for an alternative (or write it my self).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The problem with just making different size types line up is that an update to a C++ `bool` might look nonsensical when viewed via a C `int`, and an update to a C `int` might not even be visible when viewed as a C++ `bool`.  That's even assuming everything "works".

Comment: Just run the C header through a preprocessing that replaces `bool` with `int`. You can use any scripting language for that. Or even C++.

Comment: Compiling a C library with a C++ compiler is unlikely to work unless that interoperability is a design goal of the library. I think you probably need to make the C data into an opaque type and use C++-compatible functions to access the data.

Comment: The best solution is NOT to use `bool` in C code. People used `BOOL` back than. Now, if that can't be changed, the only solution I see is a terrible hack - pryor to include the library, in C++ code, `#define bool int`, and than `#undefine bool` after include.

Comment: What about changing `lib.h` to use `int values[20];` [without the `typedef` or use of `bool`]. This is compatible with the lib (i.e. no changes needed in the lib itself). In other words, all c++ code that interfaces to the lib should see an `int` definition and you only have to modify `lib.h` and not any of the actual library

Comment: @SergeyA a #define is ugly indeed, but it seems to be a good alternative in this case and works

Comment: Consider using `#include <stdbool.h>` in the C code.  The chances are good that C’s `_Bool` will be compatible with C++’s `bool`. However, that may be problematic for users of the C library in the short term. A lot depends on context not given in the question.

Comment: @CraigEstey modifying only `lib.h` is probably the best solution if one has no control over the external library. I build the lib completely from sources, so changing `lib.h` only in my C++ includes is effectively the same as changing the implementation of the library

Comment: re: `stdbool.h` it's a great idea unless you have to support Windows CE.  I'd probably give compiling the library in C++ a shot, unless you already have to support other `C` code.  Usually `-fpermissive` is all it takes.  I've found it generally far less painful to pick a compiler than all the BS necessary in the headers to get the compilers to generate compatible libraries/dlls.  YMMV

Comment: My edit above works whether using c or c++. They _both_ will see the `int` definition. That is, after the [one word] edit, `lib.h` works everywhere. And, it is backward compatible with an old binary version of the lib. Or, edit `lib.h` and change the typedef to `typedef char bool;` to save space--this _does_ require lib source and a rebuild

Comment: @user2079303 Actually, for my original comment, it probably wasn't clear that I was _not_ suggesting the typedef be removed. Just that it not be _used_ [otherwise] in `lib.h`. Then, edit all `bool` to `int` in `lib.h` [particularly in structs or arrays or globals defined there]. Then c++ sees everything as `int` and the lib compiles without changes to .c files. But, since OP can rebuild the lib, that's why I suggested the typedef edit in `lib.h` (i.e. make the c library compatible with c++'s bool being sizeof of 1). This may be cleaner overall, but requires a source rebuild.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write your own header file and use that instead of the broken one that is provided by the library:

fixed_lib.h

```
typedef struct {
  int numValues;
  int values[20];
} bArray;

int arraySize();
```

Of course, this means that you would need to maintain it in case the library is updated. However, if the library is actively maintained, then perhaps a better approach would be to send a pull request to resolve the issue upstream.

Furthermore, if there are other headers in the C library which depend on lib.h, then lib.h should really have a header guard, that must be used in your replacement as well, and you must make take care to include the replacement first.

If there is no header guard, then you would have to duplicate all such headers that you depend on, if those headers also depend on lib.h.

> I guess compiling the external library with a C++ compiler instead of a C compiler would work, correct?

It could only potentially work if the library happens to have been written in a subset of C that is also valid C++. Furthermore, this C++ compiled version would not be binary-compatible with the C version of the library, so you then cannot have other dependencies which themselves depend on this (originally) C library.

---

If modifying the C library is OK, another approach would be to fix the library header itself to use the actual boolean data type:

lib.h

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
#include <stdbool.h>
#endif

typedef struct {
  int numValues;
  bool values[20];
} bArray;

int arraySize();
```

Of course, this would require you to re-compile the library, and it would no longer be binary compatible with the original version that used `int`. Furthermore, this would make the library require C99 standard, and could no longer work in C89.

Comment: This is ok, but I would highly recommend using fixed-size standard types (int8_t, int32_t, etc) and using the packed attribute on the overall struct.  Treat this just like network data transfer - since you have no control over the other end of the transaction.

Comment: Thanks, this is more or less the route I took. I created a an internal fork of the library and applied the changes there. Now I can easily merge upstream if the library will ever change and am fully compatible with other C libraries that use the library as is.

Comment: Although this is kind of still modifying the external library (although only its include file without needing a recompilation), I accepted this as my solution since it is the one with the least overhead and maintenance cost and not as ugly as a `#define bool int` before including the header.

Comment: Also, thanks for pointing out that just compiling the library with a C++ compiler might work, but also breaks binary compatibility and might bring more harm than good.

Answer (score 2):

There is no general way to pass data directly from C++ to/from C code in this instance, since the `bool` types in the library differ from those in C++.   This means it is extremely dangerous to allow the C code direct access to data structures used by C++ code or vice versa  (e.g.   a change made in one language may not have the expected effect in the other).

The general solution is to introduce a header file that can be used from both C and C++ code, but doesn't allow access from C++ code to C code or vice versa.

This means that header must only contain declarations that are acceptable in both C and C++.    In other words, since `bool` works differently in your third party library than in C++, there should be nothing referring to `bool` in that header.

For example, a header named interface.h

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct
{
    int numValues;
    char values[20];
} interface_bArray;

int interface_arraySize();

int interface_somefunc(interface_bArray *v);

#ifndef __cplusplus
    }
#endif
```

In compiling as C++, the above wrap all of the declarations in an `extern "C"` block.   If compiling as C, it doesn't.  Assuming the C and C++ compilers interoperate, this will allow the types and functions to be used in both languages.   Note that it is important to ensure this header does NOT `#include "lib.h"` so C++ code never sees that header.   An include guard on this header may be appropriate (but unrelated to providing an interface between C++ and C code).

I'm using the prefix `interface_` in the declarations to ensure names are distinct from those in lib.h.    You can pick whatever prefix you like, as long as they don't introduce name clashes with others in your program or in lib.h.

Then a C file (say, interface.c) which will ONLY ever be compiled as C.

```
#include "interface.h"
#include "lib.h"

int interface_arraySize()
{
    return arraySize();
}

int interface_somefunc(interface_bArray *v)
{
     int i, retval;
     bArray temp;

     /*  copy data from a form understood in C++ code to form understood by C library */

     temp.numValues = v->numValues;
     for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i) temp.values[i] = !(!v->values[i]);  /* maps all non-zero to 1 */

     retval = some_function_from_lib(&temp);

     /*  copy data library back to a form understood in C++ code */

     v->numValues = temp.numValues;

     for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i) v->values[i] = !(!temp.values[i]);  /* maps all non-zero to 1 */

     return retval;
}
```

Within this C file, the only `bool` type seen is that understood by the library.

This means there is no data passed directly from C++ code to the library.  Instead a copy is made, given to the library, and then results are copied back.

C++ code which needs (indirect) use of the library obtains that by `#include "interface.h"` and NEVER includes lib.h.

To build your program, compile the library as usual (presumably using a C compiler), compile interface.c using only a C compiler, and compile other code as usual (e.g. using a C++ or C compiler as appropriate).   Then link as required.

An advantage of this approach is that, if the library is ever changed (e.g. an updated) version, then the only file in your program that needs to be updated is the interface.c and (only if the library introduces new functionality that you wish to exploit in C++ code) the interface.h.

There are two down sides.

Firstly, the costs (performance, memory,etc) of COPYING across the boundary between C++ and C are the necessary price you pay for an interface that works consistently between the two languages, when there is an incompatibility (in this case, different notion of a `bool` type between C and C++ code). If you are unwilling to accept such costs, there is no general solution - any solutions will potentially vary between C and C++ compilers, between compiler versions, etc.

Second, if the library changes, you will need to remember to check if the interface files need updating.    One part of this cost is having two data structures for the same thing - one only visible in C code, and one on the C++ that can also be passed to C code and copied from there.   You might get lucky, and find that the interface.c does not compile if the library changes.   Or you may not.  Again, I view the cost of ongoing maintenance of the interface as being a necessary cost of using the library across programming languages.     This does naturally mean that functions provided by the library must be sufficiently valuable to justify that overhead, rather than rolling a C++-specific version of it.

Comment: This is probably the cleanest solution, because it completely avoids recompiling the library and even avoids changing the included header to match the C layout. However, it comes with significant costs, which you clearly described. I'll probably go with a more lightweight solution.

Comment: I described the costs. You're assuming those costs are significant cost, but I didn't actually suggest that.   Although the cost is non-zero, without profiling l would bet you're over-estimating the runtime impact of interfacing on your program.    Optimising without evidence (testing and profiling), particularly if that potentially compromises program correctness or maintainability, is described as "premature optimisation" for a reason.

Comment: I was more referring to maintaining the bridging interface than to the runtime cost, which in my case is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

`bool` is a keyword in C++ and has size 1 byte. So when you include this header file size of `typedef` is different in C and C++. So array size will change and binary capability won't be maintained.
Changing build flags by `pragma push` will not change anything.

There are only two way to overcome this problem (besides finding/writing alternative).

Quick one is to edit `lib.h` header file and rename typedef for `bool` and remove `#ifndef __cplusplus` for it. It should do the trick without recompilation of library (if you have sources).

Other solution is to wrap library with other C source. Create `wrapper.h` which will provide bringing types and bringing function declarations. In `wrapper.c` include `wrapper.h` and `lib.h` and implement bridging to library functions and conversation between wrapped and library types. In this case there will be lots of boiler plate code but it will work for sure.

If you have library sources change typedef to `typedef int bool;` and rebuild it.

---

I come up with better solution than rename typedef for `bool`. Use define to change meaning of bool. Basically create this kind of header file:

```
// WrappedLib.h
#ifndef WRAPPED__LIB_H
#define WRAPPED__LIB_H

#ifndef __cplusplus
#error "This header file should be used only in C++ sources"
#endif

// this will fix size problem
#define bool int

extern "C" {
    #include <lib.h>
}

// restore normal behavior of bool
#undefine bool

#endif // WRAPPED__LIB_H
```

Now since macros are processed before any keyword is interpreted this will work like charm without any modification made in lib code or header.

Comment: `bool` is not required to have a size of 1 byte.

Comment: yes but most compilers are using this size. I do not now compiler which does it differently.

Comment: @MarekR I don't know of a compiler that does. bool usually is the word size, not 1 byte

Comment: 3 leading C++ compilers: [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IRGdyzOuiIsjxOm7), [g++](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4IherdtTgPBoDSbM), [VS](http://rextester.com/HKGK76889).

Comment: @Marek - in VS and (from memory) g++, `sizeof(bool)` has historically changed between compiler versions, and also been sensitive to compilation (particularly optimisation) settings.    If you can safely assume your code will only be built on particular compilers and (more risky) that `sizeof(bool)` will never change with compiler versions or compilation settings, you might get away with assuming `sizeof(bool)` is 1.   In the long run it is safer to write code that doesn't rely on such an assumption - you simply don't have control of compiler vendors.

Comment: @perer still problem that `size(int) != size(bool)` remains, so arguing if `bool` has size of 1 or two bytes is pointless.